# How to Replace a String in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string

Here's my code:

```
    Dim lQuotes As Char = Convert.ToChar(&H201C) ' “
    Dim rQuotes As Char = Convert.ToChar(&H201D) ' ”

    Dim BP01 As String =
        String.Format("<li>{0}<em>{2}</em>{1} ― <strong>{3}</strong></li>", lQuotes, rQuotes, BP1.Text, BPGB1.Text)

Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("d:Temp 1.txt", True)


objWriter.WriteLine(BP01)

objWriter.Close()
```

If BP1 Textbox is empty, That means If there's no data to input, can we replace it with "Data is empty" word or else with nothing ... like this ""

For example:

Replace BP01 to something else so that this line "Data is empty" is displayed

**Note:** I don't want to display these html codes like ... < li >, < em > etc.

Comment: Consider using `String.Replace`

Comment: So you could simply use an `If` to check if `BP1.Text` is null or empty (or is null or whitespace) and assign ´BP01`accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your input values and act accordingly instead of replacing

```
Dim BP01 As String

If (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BP1.Text) Or string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BPGB1.Text)) Then
    BP01 = "Data Is Empty"
Else
    BP01 = String.Format("<li>{0}<em>{2}</em>{1} ― <strong>{3}</strong></li>", lQuotes, rQuotes, BP1.Text, BPGB1.Text)
End If
```

If you would like to skip output entirely you can just negate (`Not`) both your `If` conditions to only act on valid input (BP1 **and** BPGB1 must not be empty).

```
If (Not string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BP1.Text) And Not string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BPGB1.Text)) Then
    BP01 = String.Format("<li>{0}<em>{2}</em>{1} ― <strong>{3}</strong></li>", lQuotes, rQuotes, BP1.Text, BPGB1.Text)
    objWriter.WriteLine(BP01)
End If
```

Comment: Hey Filburt... What If I want to completely skip a line with writing to a text file based on ur code... I mean, instead of writing "Data Is Empty" if the data is not entered, what to do to not write that specific line at all in the output text file ??? can it be possible ???

Comment: See my updated answer to skip output if no valid input is provided.

Comment: Hey Filburt... I'm still getting a blank line when i tried ur code to skip output if no valid input is provided... What i'm expecting is not to write even a blank line in the output file...

Comment: Your `objWriter ` needs to go inside the `If` or you could check if your `BP01` IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace separately.

Comment: Did you mean to remove your upvote on my answer? You can only accept and upvote once - if you click again, your upvote is revoked and I loose points (not that it hurts much in my case).

Comment: I'm sorry bro, i'm not aware of that... i juz wanted to give u one more vote bcoz i liked ur answer... even i was shocked to see that my previous vote was gone..... Can I vote ur post now again ??? I will do so.

Comment: What if BP1.Text is empty, and there's some data in BPGB1.Text and I want to write a different code if there's data in BPGB1.Text... say like ...  
`("<li>{0}<em>{2}</em>{1} ― <strong>{3}: {4}</strong></li>", lQuotes, rQuotes, BP1.Text, BPGB1.Text, BPMK.Text)`...  
  
If Both are empty I want to stick with the original code... that is  
`("<li>{0}<em>{2}</em>{1} ― <strong>{3}</strong></li>", lQuotes, rQuotes, BP1.Text, BPGB1.Text)`
  
Is it possible